# searchview loases focus on orientation change

Tags: android, fragment, screen-orientation, searchview

I am using searchview in my app with action bar and fragments. searchview is opened in the portrate mode and when we change the orientation it closes. If there is any text present in searchview it will not close on orientation chnage. I want to retain the state of searchview on orientation change even if the searchview is empty.How can i do this?i tried

```
 setRetainInstance(true);
```

But it is not working. Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

I implemented it myself since Android does not seem to save it for me.

```
    final String s = savedSearchString;
    if (s != null) {
        searchViewMenuItem.expandActionView(); // opens the action view
    }

    searchView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            searchView.setQuery(s, false); // sets the last search string on the view
        } 
    });
```

'savedSearchString' is coming from the savedInstanceState. Make sure you set the initial conent of the search window on "" and not on null (default), otherwise it won't re-open an empty window.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a boolean.
And when you open the searchView, you put boolean to true.
When you close the searchView, yout put boolean false.

In the onCreate, if the boolean = true, open the searchView.

```
final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) itemSearch.getActionView();
    searchView.setQueryHint(Html
            .fromHtml("<font color = #ffffff>Search...</font>"));

    searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //your code
        }
    });
```

Comment: i could not find out a code part where the searchview opens

Comment: for implementing the searchClickListener outside the onCreateOptionsMenu() methos which interface i have to implement in my class?

Comment: Put this in onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: You can put itemSearch.expandActionView()

Comment: Have you put : final MenuItem itemSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search); ?

Comment: control is not entering to the onSearchClick function :(